# Array package breaks custom row spacing

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to use the `array` package to create a fixed width table with text ragged right, analogous to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef). Unfortunately, even just including the `array` package breaks the ability to define **custom spacings between rows** (see example below).

How can I use the `array` package but still define custom spacings between rows?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{10cm}}
    A simple line. \\[1cm]
    A longer text that spans multiple lines. A longer text that spans multiple
    lines. A longer text that spans multiple lines. A longer text that spans
    multiple lines. \\[1cm]
    \textbf{There should be more space before this line}.
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Removing the line `\usepackage{array}` gives the expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it appeared to work without `array` is due to a misfeature of the original implementation fixed in the package.  The `\\[..]` syntax adds extra depth to the row, in the original implementation this is added to the final cell of the table, so although it notionally affects the whole row its effect depends on teh type of the final column, you only get the effect you wanted if the final column is the column with the largest depth.  Note if I add an `l` column at the start of your table you get the spacing you showed, but if I add `l` column at teh end of the row, the spacing goes.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{lp{10cm}}
    x&A simple line. \\[1cm]
    x&A longer text that spans multiple lines. A longer text that spans multiple
    lines. A longer text that spans multiple lines. A longer text that spans
    multiple lines. \\[1cm]
    x&\textbf{There should be more space before this line}.
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{10cm}l}
    A simple line.&x \\[1cm]
    A longer text that spans multiple lines. A longer text that spans multiple
    lines. A longer text that spans multiple lines. A longer text that spans
    multiple lines.&x \\[1cm]
    \textbf{There should be more space before this line}.&x
\end{tabular*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

You could increase the length argument so that it is deeper than the depth of the `p` column, however the `booktabs` spacing commands provide a better interface here, as you found.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution I found based on [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299837/tabular-row-spacing) is `\addlinespace` from the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{10cm}}
    A simple line. \\ \addlinespace[1cm]
    A longer text that spans multiple lines. A longer text that spans multiple
    lines. A longer text that spans multiple lines. A longer text that spans
    multiple lines. \\ \addlinespace[1cm]
    \textbf{There should be more space before this line}.
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: `\\[dimen]` will always add vertical space below the row in any case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{p{10cm}X}
    A simple line. & Alpha \\[1cm]
    A longer text that spans multiple lines. A longer text that spans multiple
    lines. A longer text that spans multiple lines. A longer text that spans
    multiple lines. & Beta \\[1cm]
    \textbf{There should be more space before this line}. & Delta
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\begin{tblr}{Xp{10cm}}
    Alpha & A simple line. \\[1cm]
    Beta & A longer text that spans multiple lines. A longer text that spans multiple
    lines. A longer text that spans multiple lines. A longer text that spans
    multiple lines. \\[1cm]
    Delta & \textbf{There should be more space before this line}.
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]